# Yocto build fails to fetch sources for libtalloc, how to fix that?

Tags: meta-raspberrypi

I'm trying to build Yocto for Raspberrypi2, with qt5-image, and it gives me some build errors, most I have been able to resolve with:

bitbake -c cleansstate libname
bitbake libnam

but it failts in:

---

WARNING: libtalloc-2.1.8-r0 do_fetch: Failed........

......

code 4, output:
--2017-02-04 01:09:20--  http://samba.org/ftp/talloc/talloc-2.1.8.tar.gz
Resolving samba.org (samba.org)... 144.76.82.156, 2a01:4f8:192:486::443:2
Connecting to samba.org (samba.org)|144.76.82.156|:80... failed: Connection refused.
Connecting to samba.org (samba.org)|2a01:4f8:192:486::443:2|:80... failed: Network is unreachable.

---

How can i fix that?

I am new in Building custom image using Yocto for raspberrypi. Any your suggest is important form me.

Thank you in advance

Comment: I am follow this tutorial:

http://www.jumpnowtek.com/rpi/Raspberry-Pi-Systems-with-Yocto.html

Comment: This looks like to me like you were having network issues at the time.  Try again?

Comment: Thank you Joe C. I will try again and feedback to you.

Comment: Yes done. but in the folder ...bulid/tmp/deploy/images/raspberrypi2/ the file with extension  qt5-image-raspberrypi2.tar.xz     How can i write this to micro sdicard?? Thank

Comment: That looks like an excellent subject for a new question.

Comment: Thank Joe C for your help